# Connecting two routers to create two home networks causes issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, external-hard-drive, wireless-router

My cable provider provided us with a gateway modem that has it's own built in router. I need to set up two local networks, one for guest and one for admins.

The reason is because I have a Western Digital MyCloud EX2 that is connected via ethernet and I don't want my guests to access the hard drive, only the admins.

This is my current setup:

Coaxial Cable (Internet) > Cisco Gateway > TP-LINK TL-WR841N Router > MyCloud Hard Drive.

Cisco Gateway is used as Guest network,
TP-LINK is used as admin network

This setup works to prevent my guests access to the drive, however, my TP-LINK router connection is constantly dropping and resetting, the CISCO is okay. How do I fix this disconnecting issue? I've tried a Belkin router and same disconnecting issues. I've spoke to my cable provider and they said there's no other setup I can have to restrict guests from using my hard drive since it's a wired connection to the local network.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're talking Cisco Gateway as in a cable modem, correct? Can you provide the model number?

Comment: In addition, your TP-Link router doesn't have the option to prevent guests from accessing the rest of the network (or a guest network at all)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to isolate your problem. Is the issue affecting only your WD CloudDrive? You can tell by using the internet through your TP-LINK router.

Does your TP-LINK get a constant IP address from Cisco gateway? If not, make sure it is getting a constant IP. It is best to just assign a static IP to your TP-LINK. If you use DHCP, check if the DHCP lease is very short (e.g. 10 min). Some router has trouble with existing connections when DHCP lease expired.

Also try to find out what port the WD Cloud Drive is using for incoming file request and try to setup port forwarding. Your WD CloudDrive maybe using uPnP and it does not work well across the TP-LINK and the Cisco Gateway.

Comment: Should I assign the static IP via my cisco router? When I tried "pre-assigning" a DHCP IP address to the mac address of my TP-Link in the CISCO setup, it does not get saved after I restart the router. When I try to set the WAN connection type of my TP-link to a static IP I lose internet connection completely.

Answer (score 0):

You have no access to the setup of the Cisco gateway? If you can get the Cisco configured with 2 VLANs you're all set without needing the TP-LINK. Perhaps the cable provider can configure this if you can't do it yourself. I am assuming here that the Cisco is running a DHCP server on a RFC1918 private ip range. If so you need give the TP-LINK a static IP in the same subnet as the Cisco LAN on the WAN interface. Make sure the chosen static IP is not in the DHCP pool the Cisco is using. The TP-LINK must also use another subnet on the LAN interface than it's using on the WAN interface.

If you want a more specific description you need to specify the ip address and subnet mask of the Cisco.

Comment: Do you mean you need the ip address and subnet mask to expand on your description?